# Menu 'border-right: none' not working

Tags: css, wordpress, styles, border, stylesheet

I have added menu separators on this page `http://79.170.40.241/refthecoffeefactory.co.uk/home`

I have also added the following to remove the boarder on the far right of the menu, although it doesn't seem to work.....

```
#navigation ul.nav > li.menu-item-56 {
    border-right: none !important;

}
```

Any ideas as to why?

Comment: 404 Not Found on the link ..

Comment: ok try http://79.170.40.241/refthecoffeefactory.co.uk/home

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: just took a further look.  Your border is on the "a" tag, not the table.  Still, my previous answer follows:

Looks like it's being overridden by other styles.  Looking at your style chain, you have many overlapping styles and use !important a lot.  There are ways to isolate that particular element, but you might want to revisit all your styles taking specificity and inheritance into account.  Here's a site that explains it simply and effectively:
http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/

Also, to find out which style is specifically breaking it, with Firefox or Chrome, right-click and inspect element.  You'll see that the one where you specify no border is overridden (it's crossed out).

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm using a wordpress child theme which is why !important is being used for these styles.

Answer (score 2):

The border styles are on `a` tags, not `li` tags.

This should do the work for you:

```
#menu-item-56 a {
    border-right: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#main-nav li a:last-child
{
border-right: none !important;
}
```